# VBA: Passing values to different sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a code which is meant to calculate the variance of a growing portfolio and calculate the variance 5000 times for each element included in the portfolio.
The code works as it should and no problem there.

Where I'm a little troubled is that there are 6 different co-variance matrices and the code should run on each of them.

I have included the code in a for each loop to select and use the 6 different co-variance matrices and it should work.

However I would like the output (the variance of the portfolio) to be placed in 6 different pre-defined worksheets and not the same as it is the case at the moment.

My first thought was to use a array to loop though each of the 6 new worksheets but I don't know how to implement it.

I would highly appreciate any guidance.

The code is as follows:

```
Sub kovariansmatrice()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Dim Var As Long
Dim k, j As Integer
Dim Random As Double
Dim i As Integer
Dim Fifth As Double
Dim varians As Variant
Dim Worksheet As Variant
Dim Worksheets As Variant
Dim outputs As Variant

Worksheets = Array("KVM1D", "KVM2D", "KVM3D", "KVM1M", "KVM2M", "KVM3M")
outputs = Array("Kovar1D", "Kovar2D", "Kovar3D", "Kovar1M", "Kovar2M", "Kovar3M")

For Each Worksheet In Worksheets

    For k = 100 To 150 Step 5
        Cells(2, 496) = k

            For j = 1 To 5000
                For i = 1 To 494
                    Randomize
                    Random = Rnd()
                    Worksheets("Kovarians").Cells(3, i).Value = Random
                Next i

                Fifth = WorksheetFunction.Large(Sheets("Kovarians").Range("A3:BHK3"), k)
                Worksheets("Kovarians").Cells(5, 1).Value = Fifth
                varians = Application.MMult(Application.MMult(Sheets("Kovarians").Range("A2:BHK2"), Sheets("Kovarians").Range("B11:BHL1581")), Application.Transpose(Sheets("Kovarians").Range("A2:BHK2")))
                Worksheets("Kovarians").Cells(5, 3).Value = varians

                Calculate

                Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, k) = Sheets("Kovarians").Cells(5, 3)

            Next j
    Next k

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Next Worksheet

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Robin, I had a little trouble getting the code in right

Answer (score 1):

Please Try the below

```
Sub kovariansmatrice()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Dim Var As Long
Dim k, j As Integer
Dim Random As Double
Dim i As Integer
Dim Fifth As Double
Dim varians As Variant
Dim Worksheet As Variant
Dim Worksheets As Variant
Dim outputs As Variant

Worksheets = Array("KVM1D", "KVM2D", "KVM3D", "KVM1M", "KVM2M", "KVM3M")
outputs = Array("Kovar1D", "Kovar2D", "Kovar3D", "Kovar1M", "Kovar2M", "Kovar3M")

Dim indexVal As Integer
indexVal = 0

For Each Worksheet In Worksheets

    For k = 100 To 150 Step 5
        Cells(2, 496) = k

            For j = 1 To 5000
                For i = 1 To 494
                    Randomize
                    Random = Rnd()
                    Worksheets(outputs(indexVal)).Cells(3, i).Value = Random
                Next i

                Fifth = WorksheetFunction.Large(Sheets(outputs(indexVal)).Range("A3:BHK3"), k)
                Worksheets(outputs(indexVal)).Cells(5, 1).Value = Fifth
                varians = Application.MMult(Application.MMult(Sheets(outputs(indexVal)).Range("A2:BHK2"), Sheets(outputs(indexVal)).Range("B11:BHL1581")), Application.Transpose(Sheets(outputs(indexVal)).Range("A2:BHK2")))
                Worksheets(outputs(indexVal)).Cells(5, 3).Value = varians

                Calculate

                Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, k) = Sheets(outputs(indexVal)).Cells(5, 3)

            Next j
    Next k
indexVal = indexVal + 1
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Next Worksheet

End Sub
```

Comment: How should I include it in the code above?

Since the output from KVM1D the first element in the first array should be placed in output1 which would be the first element in the second array (the one you are purposing)

Comment: Sorry, i was just trying to give you the array iteration.Can you please let me know if  `Worksheets("Kovarians")` is your output sheet that you want to send the details

Comment: What my understanding is  `Worksheets("KVM1D")` should go to  `Worksheets("Kovar1D")`, `Worksheets("KVM2D")` should go to  `Worksheets("Kovar2D")`... Am i right in my understanding?

Comment: Yes you are completely right Siva. Please have a look at the "new" code below

Comment: You Could have edited your Question it self.i will update my answer

Comment: Please don't modify your question. I will update the answer with the same code.

Comment: Please see my updated answer and check if it is as per what you expected.

Comment: Hi Siva - For now it seems to run perfectly!
I'll update you when the code has run for a while but I seems like it does what I wan't it to do.
Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi Siva
It's like the code doesn't restart the loop including the variable k when we shifts between sheets.
So it's just stock with 1 in all sheets after the first sheet.
I hope you understand

Comment: @KristianNielsen, Im sorry i didn't understand. What is the Issue?

Comment: Hi Siva
Every time the code shifts to a new sheet, it should restart the loop involving the k variable but it doesn't.

Comment: But I just found the problem I think..
In the code it says; "For k = 100 To 150 Step 5
        Cells(2, 496) = k"
but it should of cause be: For k = 100 To 150 Step 5
        Sheets(worksheets(indexval)).Cells(2, 496) = k

Comment: You need't say it as `Sheets(worksheets(indexval)).Cells(2, 496) = k` instead you can make it as `Worksheet.Cells(2, 496) = k` because, every time the loop iterates, `Worksheet` variable will point to the corresponding work sheet. Like in Iteration 1, `Worksheet` will point to "KVM1D" and in iteration to it will point to "KVM2D" and so on

Comment: No, it is not.But it doesn't make sense in using `For Each` and you using array Indexing to iterate through the worksheet array.So just suggested it.

Comment: Nice to know, I guess it would have something to say for the speed of the code?

Comment: May be, but i'm not much aware of that.